# How would i send a song index to a custom music Player?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

so im quite new to android programming and was wondering how i would go about sending a song's index from the Library `Fragment` to the Player `Fragment` and then getting the song to play automatically, using that index. So far with the code i have, nothing happens when a `ListItem` is clicked. And i mean nothing. It didn't even crash on me as expected. Here is the code...

**LibraryFragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

    songView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    songList = new ArrayList<>();

    getSongList();

    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

    songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Getting list item index
            int songIndex = position;

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LibraryFragment.class);
            // Sending songIndex to Player Fragment
            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
            getActivity().setResult(100, in);

        }
    });

    SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getActivity(), songList);
    songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

    return rootView;
}
```

**PlayerFragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Intents for fragments, they are not launchable.

Also what do you think `getActivity().setResult(100, in);` does? You certainly use that wrong.

Please read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) on fragment communication.

---

**In detail**

- your `LibraryFragment` needs to define an interface, e.g.

`public interface LibraryListener {
    void onIndexSelected(int index)
}`

- your activity has to implement this interface. In this implementation it has to deliver the index to the `PlayerFragment`, which should define a public method to do just that.
- Now your LibraryFragment can call `((LibraryListener)getActivity()).onIndexSelected(index);`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Do you know how i would send the index? I'm still slightly confused.

Comment: I've provided a short example. If you understand neither this nor the example in the documentation you should take a step back and learn how interfaces and casts work in Java.